# How to perform match query in Elasticsearch in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I wrote an Elaticsearch query for match category and name in my records.

My sample record:

```
{category: "disease", name: "Heart Diseases", dui: "D006331", url_name: "Heart Disease"}
```

I need to match my parameter with 'name' and category should be 'disease'  and 'hospital' always and wrote it like this:

```
match: {
        name: {
          query: searchString,
          fuzziness: 2,
          operator: "or"
        },
       category: ['hospital', 'disease']

      }
```

Updated code:

```
 client.search({
index: 'xpertdox',
type: 'disease',
size: 20,
body: {
  query: {
   bool: {
   must: {
    match: {
      name: {
        query: req.param('disease'),
        //fuzziness:"AUTO",
        fuzziness: 2,
        operator: "or"
      }
    }
  },
 should : [
 { term : { category: disease} }
],
minimum_should_match: 2
 }

}
```

But this is not working. I don't know where the mistake is.

Comment: what is the version of elasticsearch you're using?

Comment: I am using 5.5.0

Comment: it's not clear from your question, should the category of a single document be 'hospital' or 'disease'? or 'hospital' and 'disease' (two categories for one doc)?

Comment: I have both single and 2 categoires to compare,but for now i need to compare only one.

Comment: ok, I think I got what you need, see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

To match all categories is one doc use query below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": searchString,
            "fuzziness": 2,
            "operator": "or"
          }
        }
      },
      "should": [
        { "term": { "category": "hospital" } },
        { "term": { "category": "disease" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

`minimum_should_match` should be equal to the number of optional clauses (the clauses in "should" array).

**UPDATE**

To match one category from the list of categories, use `filter` and `terms` query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": searchString,
            "fuzziness": 2,
            "operator": "or"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": { "category": [ "hospital", "disease"] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Iolotron,I update my code to fetch where category is only disease but its giving me the results also from other categories like doctor and hospital.Can you please get me some help.Thanks.

Comment: if you put only disease, you should also change "minimum_should_match" to be 1. A value greater than the number of optional clauses, or a value less than 1 will never be used.